# Why does Python remove the last character of a string?

Tags: python, strip

For example, if I do this `str(bin(66))` I get `0b1000010`, but if I do this `str(bin(66)).strip("0b")`, I get `100001` (notice the missing '0').

I think I'm misusing the strip function.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`strip` strips characters from both sides. Use `lstrip` to only strip characters from the left-hand side.

```
In [27]: str(bin(66)).strip("0b")
Out[27]: '100001'

In [28]: str(bin(66)).lstrip("0b")
Out[28]: '1000010'
```

Alternatively, just use the `format` method:

```
In [38]: '{:b}'.format(66)
Out[38]: '1000010'
```

Comment: For example `'0b0011'.lstrip('0b')` returns '11' which is hardly what OP needs, see Ashwini's response.

Comment: @bereal: Well, probably OP needs binary representation (`'{:b}'.format(3)`), so `'0b0011'.lstrip('0b')` returning `'11'` is right solution (as `0b0011 == 0b11`).

Answer (score 6):

From [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip):

```
str.strip([chars])
```

> Return a copy of the string with the leading and trailing characters
>   removed. The chars argument is a string specifying the
>   **set of characters** to be removed. If omitted or None, the chars argument defaults to removing whitespace. The chars argument is **not** a
>   **prefix** or **suffix**; rather, all combinations of its values are stripped

So, you're thinking that `str.strip` will remove the prefix `"0b"`, but it doesn't work that way. It simply considers `'0'` and `'b'` as two different characters and removes them from the start and end of the string. Same thing applies to both `str.rstrip` and `str.lstrip` they don't remove prefix or suffix, but combination of individual characters.

For example:

```
>>> "0b00101".lstrip("0b")  #just an example case, removes more than just "0b"
'101'
```

Another example:

```
>>> strs = "foofoofoobarfoo"
>>> strs.lstrip('fo')
'barfoo'

>>> if strs.startswith('fo'):          #this works fine
       print strs.replace('fo','',1)
...     
ofoofoobarfoo
```

For binary numbers apart from solutions suggested by @unutbu, you can also try `slicing`:

```
>>> str(bin(66))[2:]
'1000010'
```

or `format`:

```
>>> format(66, 'b')
'1000010'
```